# Generating dom selector using function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate the top 3 variables using the new roomTotal function at the bottom by putting "lounge" in "idt" argument. I want to use the same code in other tables with different IDs. But it's not working and I can't figure out why. Please help.

```
    var Vol = document.querySelectorAll("#lounge .vol input");
    var Qty = document.querySelectorAll("#lounge .qty input");
    var t = document.querySelectorAll("#lounge .total input");



function roomTotal(idt) {
    var w = "\"#" + idt;
    var Vol = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .vol input\"");
    var Qty = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .qty input\"");
    var T = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .total input\"");
    }
```

Snippet of the html

```
<table id="lounge">
    <tr>
    <td class="item">Upright Piano</td>
    <td class="vol">
        <input type="number" value="0" placeholder="0">
    </td>
    <td class="qty">
        <input type="number" value="0" placeholder="0">
    </td>
    <td class="total">
        <input type="number" name="" value="60" placeholder="60">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="item">Upright Piano</td>
    <td class="vol">
        <input type="number" value="0" placeholder="0">
    </td>
    <td class="qty">
        <input type="number" value="0" placeholder="0">
    </td>
    <td class="total">
        <input type="number" name="" value="40" placeholder="40">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If it's an ID it should start with `#`, not `.` which is for matching class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\"` <--- thats why ...

Let's say `w` is `#lounge` ...

Your code

`var Vol = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .vol input\"");`

is being evaluated to:

`var Vol = document.querySelectorAll('#lounge .vol input"');`

You need to remove the escaped double quote.

In your case it should be:

```
function roomTotal(idt) {
    var w = "#" + idt;
    var Vol = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .vol input");
    var Qty = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .qty input");
    var T = document.querySelectorAll(w + " .total input");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Flash but w would be "#lounge

Comment: so it would evaluate to `"#lounge .vol input"` ... and as there is nothing like `input"`, neither `"#lounge` ... it selects nothing. Just remove all `\"`

Comment: Thanks flash but there is and input. its basically from a table and there are lot of inputs.

Comment: please try my code from edit... the problem is that you are adding double quotes... should be `string + string` not `'"string' + 'string"'` it tries to select `input"` with a double quote attached to it... not `input` itself... same with beginning.

Comment: ok thanks you for your help flash i'll try it first thing tomorrow and let you know..

Comment: Hello mate I tried it and while it did give me the right variable when calling in side the queryselector it adds an extra ‘’ so i end up with ‘“#lounge .vol input”’

Comment: No worries Flash I got it working.. function roomTotal(p, g) {

  var v = "#" + p;

  var Vol = document.querySelectorAll(v + " .vol input");
  var Qty = document.querySelectorAll(v + " .qty input");
  var te = document.querySelectorAll(v + " .total input");
  var rw = document.querySelectorAll(v + " tr");